# How can i connect Remote MS access using pyodbc

Tags: python, django, pyodbc, django-pyodbc

How can i connect to remote MS Access DB using pyodbc, before i can able to connect to MS SQL server using pyodbc via freetds. But if i use the same freetds configuration for remote access, 'i'm not getiing the success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Can you get it to work from another client? It isn't easy to help without any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

freeTDS is ODBC driver for using the TDS communication protocol. MS SQL Server uses the TDS protocol.

Access does not, so it is not a surprise that it doesn't work.  What you need is an ODBC driver for the Jet engine used by Access. And it exists. It is called libmdb. You can install the packages to get it set up.

Read [MDB Tools Installation Guide](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/install/book1.htm) for more information.